# how to reading input file list into action?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I can not read arraylist at action. Coming object file to Controller-action

```js
var fileCollection = [];
 var files = $("#fileChooser").get(0).files;
 $.each(files, function (i, file) {
 fileCollection.push(file)
});
 var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", fileCollection);
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/Home/FileUpload",
  data: formData,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
});
```

```html
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="fileChooser" multiple />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file `input` has no files at first. So you can only get files from it when the user interacts with it. For this use the `change` event. It will trigger whenever the value of the `input` has been changed.

So add this event listener around your code which will be called whenever `change` is triggered.

Also try to add each `File` to the `FormData` object instead of adding an array of `File` objects. The `value` parameter of the [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) method of `FormData` can take the following arguments according to MDN.

> The field's value. This can be a USVString or Blob (including subclasses such as File).

```js
$("#fileChooser").on('change', function(event) {

  var fileCollection = [];
  var formData = new FormData();
  var files = event.target.files;     // Get the current files.
  
  $.each(files, function (i, file) {
    formData.append("file", file);
  });
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/FileUpload",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="fileChooser" multiple />
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking. Are you asking how to read the **sent** FormData on the server? Or how to read it before sending?